# pdsh input from file possible?

Tags: ssh, command-line, pipe, pdsh

I can pipe data from one command to another, example:

```
$ echo test | cat
test
```

[Unsure of what to call](https://superuser.com/questions/480599/with-regards-to-piping-commands-what-are-the-greater-than-and-less-than) the operation I can get a similar effect using:

```
$ cat < <(echo test)
test
```

Where `<(echo test)` is a bashism for creating a file on the fly. Using regular files it looks like:

```
$ cat file
test
$ cat < file
test
```

This works equally well over ssh:

```
$ ssh server cat < <(echo test)
test
```

Using the ssh-example as a base one might think you could do something like:

```
$ pdsh -a cat < <(echo test)
```

But no data is sent to cat on the connected machines and the command never terminates.

`tee` seem quite able to send what it receives on stdin to more than one place:

```
$ tee >(cat) >(cat) < <(echo test) 
test
test
test
```

Is it possible to achieve the same over `pdsh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get in contact with one of the `pdsh` developers and learned the following:

> What you want is "stdin broadcast" and unfortunately support for this
>   was never added to pdsh. It would be a nice feature, but there was not
>   historically much need for it, so it wasn't ever done.

Which seem to confirm what has already been established in this post.

However, it was followed by:

> BTW, it isn't that it is *impossible* to do the stdin broadcast.
>   Parallel launchers that are part of HPC schedulers can do it, like
>   srun(1) and the like. The mechanism is that stdin is read in once,
>   then copied to a buffer for each remote process, i.e. the duplication
>   is done inside of the parallel launcher.
>
> The reason for the follow-up is that there are some misleading answers
>   on [that stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544052/pdsh-input-from-file-possible/).
>
> Another way to get around the serial for-loop problem would be to run
>   ssh from GNU parallel or pdsh -R exec. Example with pdsh -R exec:
>
> $ pdsh -R exec -w host[0-10] bash -c 'ssh %h cat < <(echo  test)'
>
> Of course the drawback here is that you are creating the temporary
>   file for redirection N times. Might  be better to put your output into
>   a local file and then just cat that file to each ssh command.
>
> The benefit of pdsh/parallel over a for loop is that you get the
>   parallelism.

In my own tests I had some trouble getting that exact example working:

```
root@master# pdsh -R exec -w host1 bash -c 'ssh %h cat < <(echo test)'
host1: bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
host1: bash: -c: line 0: `ssh n1 cat < <(echo test)'
pdsh@master: host1: bash exited with exit code 1
```

One small tweak gets it alive, and that is using a "normal" file:

```
root@master# cat data.txt
test from file
root@master# pdsh -R exec -w host1 bash -c 'ssh %h cat < data.txt'
host1: test from file
```

Conclusion: `pdsh` could grow a feature to handle what I was asking for better, but even as it is now there are ways to achieve what I asked for.

Answer (score 3):

As `pdsh` doesn't support stdin forwarding/broadcasting, you could consider using `clush` from the [ClusterShell project](https://github.com/cea-hpc/clustershell) as drop-in replacement for `pdsh`, which has support for stdin broadcasting:

```
$ clush -a cat < <(echo test)
n1c01: test
n2c01: test
n1c02: test
n2c02: test
```

In addition, `clush` has nice output gathering features (no need external pipe to `dshback` for example), like shown here:

```
$ clush -ab cat < <(echo test)
---------------
n[1-2]c[01-02] (4)
---------------
test
```

See [clush's standard input bindings](https://clustershell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/clush.html?standard-input-bindings#standard-input-bindings).

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the remote command, so that the entire command runs on the remote host(s).  e.g.

```
pdsh -a 'cat < <(echo test)'
```

Without the quotes, **only** the `cat` runs on the remote host.  The redirection (`<`) and the [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) `<(echo test)` run on the local host.

When there's only one remote host consuming the ouput of `echo test` (e.g. with the `ssh` command), this works...but when there are multiple remote hosts wanting to consume that output (e.g. because you used `pdsh` instead of `ssh`), it won't work.

Comment: What you suggest is not what I wan't to achieve. I want `pdsh` to copy the incoming data stream to all the outgoing remote shell connections. The "file" I want to `<` into "cat" is not available on the target machines, only the machine where I run `pdsh`. That is also how I want it to be. I don't want to make a copy of the data on the remote host before running the command.

Comment: It won't, and it can't.  And it's not pdsh's fault, that's just how redirection works in the shell.   If you want all hosts to process exactly the same data, use `pdcp -a datafile /tmp/` (or to some safer location not vulnerable to race conditions if there are other users who might create a sneaky symlink or something in a world-writable dir like  /tmp) **before** running the `pdsh` command to process it.

Comment: you could write a for loop wrapper around ssh (so that the local host is running the process substitution once for each ssh command), but then you'd lose all the useful features of `pdsh` which highlight just how crappy a solution it is to write a for loop around ssh.

Comment: Avoiding the for-loop was precisely why I asked the question.

Comment: your choices, then, are for-loop crappiness or pdcp+pdsh (or one of the other alternatives like clusterssh, but none of them will overcome the shell-can't-duplicate-redirection-streams problem either, so you'll still have to copy the data to each host).

Comment: I was kinda hoping that ‘pdsh’ could split the stream up much in the same way as ‘tee’ does, but if it can’t I guess I’m out of luck.

Comment: BTW, instead of copying with pdcp or whatever, an alternative is to put the data file on shared storage (e.g. NFS or Samba or whatever) where all hosts can access it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the reason why you want the data to be sent to multiple computers is that you cannot easily put it into a temporary file and transfer the file to the remote machines. Maybe the output is generated continuously, maybe it is too big to fit on the disk.

GNU Parallel's `--tee` can help you:

```
seq 1000 |
  parallel --tee --pipe ssh {} wc ::: server1 server2
```

Replace `seq 1000` and `wc` with your commands.

On an unmodified GNU/Linux system this should be able to run on 250 servers. If you need more, you will run out of file handles, and will have to change `ulimit -n` or `nofile` in `/etc/security/limits.conf` or `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`.

Behind the scenes the following is started (It is a little more complicated because GNU Parallel collects stdout and stderr from the commands but the principle is the same):

```
... | tee >(ssh server1 wc) >(ssh server2 wc) >/dev/null
```

So performance is comparable to `tee`. But it also means that there will be an `ssh` to all the servers in parallel - not just a few at a time.